# How can I put if statement inside a macro in jinja2?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have the following macro, in which I want to put if statement if it is possible.

```
{% macro input(name, plc, required=true, type='text', class='validate') -%}
  <input name="{{ name }}" placeholder="{{ plc }}" type="{{ type }}" class="{{ class }}" value="{{ session.get(name) }}" { % if required %} required {% endif %}>
{%- endmacro %}
```

Hence, it throws the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endif'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endmacro'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'macro'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess it's typo, there was an extra blanc character in `{ % if required %}`, it should be `{% if required %}`